# Equality vs Approximation which one has the precedence?

Tags: approximation

Which one of these statements is true?

```
4/3 ≈ 1.3 = 8/6
```

(i.e. 4/3 ≈ 1.3 and 4/3 = 8/6)

```
4/3 ≈ 1.3 ≈ 8/6
```

Edit:

Is this statement true or false?

```
4/3 ≈ 1.3 ≈ 8/6 = 12/9 = 16/12 ≈ 1 ≈ 1.3 ≈ 4/3
```

Edit:

This sign **≈** denotes approximation.
And this sign **=** obviously denotes equality.

Comment: Did we (Browning and myself) help you at all? The point you raise, upon more consideration, is an incredibly subtle one - subtle enough that it took us a moment to see what you were even asking. It is also extremely important. I usually don't return to questions to ask this, but I was worried about this one. How do you feel about this now, particularly my comment clarifying what 'false' means?

Comment: @TheCount You actually answered my question. But I need some kind of proof for the answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Proof of what?

Comment: @TheCount I mean resources for example.

Comment: Well, how do you *define* the symbol $\approx$? Without a clear definition, there is no way to say if $4/3\approx 1.3$ is true or not. And unfortunately, I don't think there is a precise definition for it.

Answer (score 2):

4/3 ≈ 1.3 ≈ 8/6 = 12/9 = 16/12 ≈ 1 ≈ 1.3 ≈ 4/3 is shorthand for
(4/3 ≈ 1.3 and 1.3 ≈ 8/6 and 8/6 = 12/9 and 12/9 = 16/12 and 16/12 ≈ 1 and 1 ≈ 1.3 and 1.3 ≈ 4/3).  Your compound statement is true iff each part is true.

Comment: What is a compound statement?

Comment: It is a statement with multiple claims in it.

Answer (score 1):

The second is true. In the second, you wrote that both $4/3$ and $8/6$ are 'close enough for our purposes' to $1.3$. In the first, you have that $1.3=8/6$, which it objectively does not.

I just reread your title. Each and every relative statement, involving $\cong, =, \equiv, ~, \leq$, etc. should be true along the way. Have I resolved your concern?

Edit: Responding to your added portion of your question, I would say that your statement at the end is true, provided you don't mind saying that $1$ is 'close enough' to $1.3$, for example. That very well may be true in some applications, but most people would do a double-take. Although, it is a matter of preference and opinion at that point. Also of note: your final conclusion seems to be that $4/3$ is 'close enough' to itself, which it darn well better be!

Comment: So, they have the precedence from the left to the right.

Comment: 4/3 ≈ 1.3 = 8/6 is shorthand for the statement (4/3 ≈ 1.3 and 1.3 = 8/6).  Since the second part is false, the statement is false.

Comment: @user37421 no, they don't. consider the statement "numbers are even". even though it is partially true, it is not entirely true, and is therefore false. the statement "the sky is blue, the grass is green, and the sun is purple" would also be considered false.